# Position an image outside of it's container

Tags: css, mobile, position

I'm struggling with working out how to get this to work.

I have an image inside a `wide-header` div. It's a responsive header, so the image is set to `width:100%` to make the banner resize to the size of it's container.

Problem is, the image needs to sit full width, but the container has a 10px margin on either side.

The HTML **cannot change** as it's CMS based. The banner must sit inside `region-content` with it's margin of `10px` either side

I have successfully managed to push the image to the left most edge by using a `position:relative` on the image and placing it `left:-10px` to counter the left side gap.

Problem I am having is doing the same on the opposite side, as I cannot extend the width. The banner needs to be 20px wider... but  it's set as a percentage based width so simply adding 20px doesn't work.

Essentially I need to work out how to get this to work as 100% + 20px.

It's for mobile so `border-box:box-sizing` could be used, but I cannot utilise this correctly, though I am sure a solution may require it.

**[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zr8xp/)**

**HTML**

```
<div id="region-content">
    <div class="content">
          <!-- HEADER IMAGE -->
            <div id="wide-header">
                <img src="http://i.telegraph.co.uk/multimedia/archive/02474/cat-eyebrows-1_2474686k.jpg" width="1400" height="475" alt="">
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
body{margin:0 auto;}

#region-content{
margin-left: 10px;
margin-right: 10px;
    outline:1px solid red;
}

#wider-header{
width: 100%;
box-sizing: border-box;
overflow: hidden;
max-height: 300px;
text-align: center;
background-color: #333;
}

#wide-header img {
width: 100%;
height: auto;
margin: 0 auto;
max-width: 1300px;
    position:relative;
    left:-10px;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Another way is to do the following (although you might have to look at your other content inside the #wide-header)

```
position:relative;
left:-10px;
```

to

```
position:absolute;
left:0;
right:0;
```

I have updated your fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/zr8xp/3/

Answer (score 2):

If you want increase the width more than 100%. Try **width:105%;** see this editted [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zr8xp/9/) its the same as 100% + 20px

```
width:105%;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
#wide-header img {
height: auto;
margin: 0 -10px;
max-width: 1300px;
}
```

Another approach worth considering is using a background image instead. E.g.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<style media="all">

body{margin:0 auto; 
    background-image: url(http://i.telegraph.co.uk/multimedia/archive/02474/cat-eyebrows-1_2474686k.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover; 
    background-position: 50% 0;
}

#region-content{
margin-left: 10px;
margin-right: 10px;
outline:1px solid red;

min-height: 600px;
}

#wider-header{
width: 100%;
box-sizing: border-box;
overflow: hidden;
max-height: 300px;
text-align: center;
background-color: #333;
}


</style>

</head>
<body>

<div id="region-content">
    <div class="content">
        <div id="wide-header">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are not bothered about old versions of IE you can try this way:

```
width: calc(100% + 20px);
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/zr8xp/2/)

Comment: Thanks, just found this myself. I am checking to see if Opera and Android Browser are needed as they do not support this.

Answer (score 1):

I update your jsfidle by adding some css modifications:
link: http://jsfiddle.net/zr8xp/8/

**CSS:**

```
body{margin:0 auto;}

#region-content{
margin-left: 10px;
margin-right: 10px;
    outline:1px solid red;
}

#wider-header{
width: 100%;
box-sizing: border-box;
overflow: hidden;
max-height: 300px;
text-align: center;
background-color: #333;
padding-left: 10px;
padding-right: 10px;
}

#wide-header img {
width: 100%;
height: auto;
margin: 0 auto;
max-width: 1300px;
    position:relative;

}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="region-content">
    <div class="content">
          <!-- HEADER IMAGE -->
            <div id="wide-header">
                <img src="http://i.telegraph.co.uk/multimedia/archive/02474/cat-eyebrows-1_2474686k.jpg" width="1400" height="475" alt="">
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I did this by putting my img in a DIV and set the div style: float:right;width:0px;overflow:visible;

This created the image to the right of main content div, outside of the width of my header and other content.